# The result doesn't show up on the local host

Tags: angular, typescript, service, observable, httpclient

I want to iterate through 'cars' array

```
<div *ngFor="let car of cars">
    The {{ car.name }} of model {{ car.model }} has milage of {{ car.milage }}.
</div>
```

So, I created a database with fields of the same values (id, name, model, milage). The database works fine with the server, so I began to link the back-end with the front-end by adding 'HttpClient' to the service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Car } from './car';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TransportationService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCar(): Observable<Car[]> {
    return this.http.get<Car[]>('/cars/');
  }
```

I created a cars vaariable of type Cars[] in app.component.ts, but there is an error that says:
**Type 'Observable<Car[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Car[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.**

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TransportationService } from './transportation.service';
import { Car } from './car';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  cars: Car[];

  constructor (private transportationService: TransportationService) {
    this.cars = this.transportationService.getCar()
  }
```

I tried changing type of car to 'any', but I can't see any result on the browser.
What should I do?

Comment: You'd need to subscribe to `getCar` to get a value from observable: `this.transporationService.getCar().subscribe( cars: Car[] => { this.cars = cars });`

Comment: It says: **Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Car[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the observable for it to begin publishing values.
https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing
[image: Angular subscribe to observable]